# How to discover boost DLL dependencies in Cassablanca (cpprestsdk) in CMake

Tags: boost, dll, cmake

This is my very first post so bear with me. Here is my setup:

I recently started using Cassablanca (cpprestsdk) on Windows 10 64bit.

I am using Microsofts package manager (vcpkg):

https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

I am not using Visual Studio although I am using its compiler. I have created a CMake project which creates a DLL that uses essentially the intro project from the cpprestsdk: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial

The end goal is that I want this DLL that I am creating to be called from another existing DLL from a legacy application.

Now I have searched around and I have already figured out how to make this work.

The other DLL simply links with this new DLL and calls the function I am interested in.

After some searching, I found that the my new DLL needs to link with the following:

target_link_libraries( PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest                                 cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal                                  cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal                                          cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_openssl_internal)

More searching and I found I need to specify the location of zlib and openssl:

set(ZLIB_ROOT         "${VCPKG_HOME_WIN}/zlib_x64-windows")
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR  "${VCPKG_HOME_WIN}/openssl-windows_x64-windows")

This is all well and good and works just fine. Then I came to boost. When installing the cpprestsdk with vcpkg it is smart enough to download all the boost it will ever need, so there are a ton of boost directories with a ton of DLLs.

When I attempted to call a function from my DLL from the legacy application the DLL failed to load because it could not find its dependency DLLs. I copied over the restsdk, openssl, and zlib dlls to the legacy application but I did not know what boost dlls to copy over.  Obviously I could shotgun it, and simply copy over all the boost dlls that vcpkg downloaded as a part of the restsdk but that seems like overkill.

Finally I wasn't sure what to do so I built my entire CMake project in Visual Studio. Somehow Visual Studio was smart enough to figure this out, and in the output directory of my project, it put the following boost DLLs:

boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_68.dll
boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_68.dll

So I figured I would take a shot and I copied these libraries over and lo and behold, everything worked. The legacy DLL successfully loaded my DLL now that it had all the right dependencies.

Stranger still, I decided to take each one out to see if they were both truly needed. It turns out, everything works fine if I removed the boost_system dll but not if I removed the boost_date_time dll.

So at the end of the day, the only boost dll I need was boost_date_time, so it seems even Visual Studio was wrong.

Finally that brings us to my question, how in the world am I supposed to figure out exactly which dll my CMake project needs when the only thing I can go by is that the cpprestsdk needs boost via this statement?

target_link_libraries( PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest                                 cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal                                  cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal                                          cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_openssl_internal)

I guess I am hoping the answer isn't 'it depends' on what boost functions my code is actually calling and I don't know the answer to that because I don't know what boost functions the cpprestsdk actually calls based on what cpprestsdk functions my code calls.

Thanks for your time.

The whole CMake file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

include(GenerateExportHeader)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

project(mydll)

set(mydll.SOURCES <source files>)

add_library(mydll SHARED ${mydll.SOURCES})

generate_export_header(mydll
                       BASE_NAME mydll_exports 
                       EXPORT_MACRO_NAME mydll_EXPORTS
                       EXPORT_FILE_NAME mydll_EXPORTS.h
                       STATIC_DEFINE mydll_EXPORTS_BUILT_AS_STATIC)

find_package(cpprestsdk CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(mydll PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest
cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal
cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal
cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_openssl_internal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the tool DependencyWalker (depends.exe) is the right answer for this.

It showed all the other dlls were system dlls and my application was probably loading them from the system, whereas the dlls I needed to add, it showed those dlls as missing dependencies when I used it on the cpprestsdk_2_10d.dll. This is kind of what I was after, which was what dlls I really need to package with my dll in order to resolve these dependency issues. I think I will go ahead and mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I may have partially figured out the answer. The 'dumpbin' utility with Visual Studio can partially do this for you:

Image has the following dependencies:

```
HTTPAPI.dll  
WINHTTP.dll  
bcrypt.dll  
CRYPT32.dll  
boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_69.dll  <- I had to add this
SSLEAY32.dll  <- I had to add this
LIBEAY32.dll  <- I had to add this
zlibd1.dll  <- I had to add this
KERNEL32.dll  
MSVCP140D.dll  
CONCRT140D.dll  
WS2_32.dll  
VCRUNTIME140D.dll
ucrtbased.dll
```

The issue here is even this isn't a perfect answer because I didn't add, nor do I have httpapi.dll, winhttp.dll, bcrypt.dll, and crypt32.dll. It only is probably working because none of my code actually calls any functions from those libraries. If they are really required, then vcpkg manager should have probably downloaded them as dependencies as well, but it did not so I have no way to get them in the current environment. I am still not satisfied with this answer.